# Gtk-WARNINGs while installing and/or starting up VMware

Tags: vmware, gtk, vmware-player, vmware-workstation

Keep getting these errors when trying to install VMware player on 16.04 i can ignore them and push through but then VMware pegs the CPU every 10min

> sudo ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle
>   Extracting VMware
>   Installer...done.
>
> (vmware-installer.py:15056): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme
>   engine in module_path: "murrine",
>
> ... (repeat 20 times) ...
>
> (vmware-installer.py:15056): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme
>   engine in module_path: "murrine",
>
> (vmware-installer.py:15056): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme
>   engine in module_path: "murrine", Gtk-Message: Failed to load module
>   "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version (0.30-2.1ubuntu1).
libcanberra-gtk-module set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Just to be sure - you see those errors, but the install itself is finishing and VMware itself works, right? I am asking as i am running vmware myself since years and do see the murrine errors as well if i startup VMware from cli - but without effects.

Comment: Yes i can push through but like you would get the errors every time i start the player from cli

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory that required module is not installed.

Try installing the module, that should fix the error.

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Note: Since VMware provides you a .bundle file which is basically an executable, it will not check the repository and install the required packages. Whenever dealing with .run or .bundle executable its best to read the README for dependencies and install them.

Comment: says i already got the newest version

Comment: Okay not sure whether this is applicable with the new version as well, here is an excerpt from the VmWare community page:

**As for the GTK errors re: canberra-gtk-module, they're innocuous. You may ignore them.**

Source: [link](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/453282)

Comment: Regarding ignoring them - yes that was my knowledge as well.

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*` once.
Seen this solution on a couple of pages to work for whom installing libcanberra-gtk-module did not work..

Answer (score 1):

[image: VMware Workstation 12.5.5 installation error in ubuntu 17.04]

I solved this error by installing `murrine-themes` from synaptic or command line by:

```
sudo apt-get install murrine-themes
```

Packages `gtk2-engines-murrine` and `libcanberra-gtk-module` were already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the command without the graphical interface

```
sudo ./VMware-Remote-Console-10.0.4-11818843.x86_64.bundle --console
```

specially if you need, as i did, to re-install the remote console only to uninstall it ;-)